# Graphical interface for Graphiz for Mac OS?

Tags: macos, graphviz, graphing

I installed the Graphviz GUI from pizelmap.com, but it appears to only be a viewer for .dot Graphviz files. I am looking for a graphical *editor*, where I can create diagrams by pointing and clicking--just like the iPhone app Instaviz.

I would rather not code graphs by hand.

Does anyone know of anything--preferably free?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Mac port of Graphviz](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/) from the same people who do `Instaviz`?  Otherwise, a not cost-free option is [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) which has been the graphical editor of choice on OS X for years; it uses Graphviz under the covers and understands .dot files.  If you want to go hard-core, there's a port of the basic AT&T graphviz and some language wrappers available through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=graphviz).

Answer (score 0):

[Graph Galaxy](https://apps.apple.com/cn/app/graph-galaxy/id1473722262?mt=12) is an interactive program to edit graphs.

Graph Galaxy builds on top of the Graphviz, and provides an out-of-the-box environment to edit graphs. We are able to quickly sketch graphs on canvas without thinking the DOT source code. In addition, Graph Galaxy provides some features to help editing graphs for better experience:

- Outline. The outline panel shows the table of contents, which gives us a quick insight about how the graphs are structured.
- Import and Export. Graph Galaxy can read the .gv files, and export the graphs to various formats like PDF, SVG, JPEG, PNG, and DOT.
- Table Editing. The elaborate table operations allow us to create a complex and irregular table easily.
- Hand-Drawn. The stroke can be transformed to hand-drawn, which is useful for prototyping.

Comment: It's quite expensive, so I would be worried that development stops suddenly. But it does look good.